# Apple Notes: Could someone help write a script for me that opens Notes.app, creates blank new note, opens note in sep window, bring to front?

Tags: shortcut, script, desktop, notes.app, customization

The kind of shortcut I'm looking for is essentially: double-click an icon on right screen, launch "NEW NOTE", POP it to FRONT, so I can immediately begin typing or paste my selection into.

I'm not a programmer or scriptor, so would like to ask if someone can create a script that enables me to do this?

My use case is I have ADHD, and if I can't see my various work tools, I easily forget they're there. I use two display screens, left for primary apps, right for support tools/utils (Notes, MusicPlayer, Calendar, Messaging windows, Finder windows, ToDoist kanban/board view). So that screen is always filled, my 2 or 3 notes get covered over by foreground tools that have been expanded etc. Suddenly I need to add a new "note to self" to remind me of something, or I need to open a new note window to paste in a web selection on my browser.

In all these cases I can't easily and conveniently "bring all notes to front", because (a) no keyboard command exists in Notes, (b) My Menubar is on left screen, but my focus is often on my right screen, so mousing over to click "bring to front" is a cognitive distractor. "Expose" is not always the answer when I've often got so many things displayed, I can't easily find my Notes app UI.

Someone may have entirely different solution. I'm open but this would be optimal for my workflow. Appreciate any help.

======

P.S. to mods:
I've read all 3 of these related threads, they don't solve my need or the code & formatting is something I don't understand.

1. [Link to a note in Apple Notes, from another note](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332100/link-to-a-note-in-apple-notes-from-another-note)
2. [How do I use AppleScript to open a specific note from Apple's Notes application?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376584/how-do-i-use-applescript-to-open-a-specific-note-from-apples-notes-application)
3. [Is there a way to create a shortcut in Finder to an Apple Note?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420474/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-shortcut-in-finder-to-an-apple-note)

Comment: Do you need 'reach to needed note as fast and as simple as possible so that I can edit it' or do you want 'desktop shortcut to specific Apple note in separate window so that I can edit it'?

Comment: @AivarPaalberg Thanks. I want  'desktop shortcut to specific Apple note in separate window so that I can edit it'?

Comment: NOTE: I just completely rewrote and edited my original post here. I think it's a lot more clear now. Maybe that's one reason why I didn't get an answer.

Comment: "Suddenly I need to add a new "note to self" to remind me of something, or I need to open a new note window to paste in a web selection on my browser." I don't know what is 'web selection', but you can easily highlight text in browser, tap with two fingers to open pop-up menu, select Share > Notes and new note with selected text entered into it is opened for you.

Comment: Can't you just trigger Spotlight with Cmd-Space, type "Notes" and press Enter to switch to Notes.app?

Comment: @nohillside Well sure, but i never use Spotlight in my workflow, it disconnects my focus... It would take a lot to explain why but in short ADHD. However, that does prompt the idea of using Siri. Anyone know what that voice command would be? Potentially "open new note in Apple Notes".